# How do I customize a UITableview right, top and bottom border?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

How can I set right, left, top and bottom border with color on UITableview in swift?

Thanks,

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this for full border:

```
yourtable.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourtable.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: 153/255, green: 153/255, blue:0/255, alpha: 1.0 ).CGColor
yourtable.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

This is for bottom border:

```
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yourtable.frame.size.height - width, width:  yourtable.frame.size.width, height: yourtable.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = width
yourtable.layer.addSublayer(border)
yourtable.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: thanks... it worked!! One more question can we have auto height of the Uitableview ..so that its height  increase or decreasing depeneds on data comes in ?(sorry it is not related to the same subject)

Comment: thank you very much! it worked and I saved a lot of research time ;-)

Comment: @AlexWoe89 Welcome anytime :)

Comment: that's great! Worked

Comment: @CodeOverRide Thanks :)

Comment: this is beautiful, thank you. Works with Swift 3, too!

Answer (score 15):

```
extension UIView {
    func addBorderTop(size size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        addBorderUtility(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: size, color: color)
    }
    func addBorderBottom(size size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        addBorderUtility(x: 0, y: frame.height - size, width: frame.width, height: size, color: color)
    }
    func addBorderLeft(size size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        addBorderUtility(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: frame.height, color: color)
    }
    func addBorderRight(size size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        addBorderUtility(x: frame.width - size, y: 0, width: size, height: frame.height, color: color)
    }
    private func addBorderUtility(x x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

I am going to open source my extension classes at some point.

Edit: Here you go, I update the functions in here https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Comment: I sure hope you'll factor out all of those copied & pasted statements into a utility method.

Comment: All four methods are identical except for the size of the frame. Figure out how to write a utility method that takes a `CGRect` argument for the border's frame, then use it to create the border layer and add it as a sublayer.

Comment: I've tried using it, but the border line is sticking out to the right, for the `addBorderTop`

Comment: thats weird, how much px does it stick out?

Comment: I found that I add to place this code in viewDidAppear before it would work. viewDidLoad did not work.

Answer (score 4):

> **if you want to give the border to tableview with color use below code
>   for swift 3 :**

```
yourTableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
yourTableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```