# Border a TableView section

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm programming a birthday reminder app and I want to border only the section which include the cells of "birthday boys".
What I did is to border each "birthay boy" cell individually but this generates a big green line between cells as the following image shows:

[image: What I have]

So what I want is to not have any green line between cells of the "birthday boys" section. I only want a green border for the whole section and I don't know how to make it possible.

This is my code right now:

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return searchController.isActive ? searchResults.count : sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection sectionIndex: Int) -> String? {
        return titles[sectionIndex]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendCell") as! FriendCell
        let contact = searchController.isActive ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        ...

        if (contact.bdayToday(birthday: contact.birthday)) {
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
            ...

        }
        ...

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchController.isActive ? searchResults.count : sections[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        if isFiltering {
            selectedContact = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        }
        else {
            selectedContact = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        }
        return indexPath
    }
```

I hope you can solve my doubt! Thanks!

Comment: [This can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011564/2804581)